# How to notify user if browser contents change?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, browser-addons, notifications

Let's say for example I have multiple different browsers that I use to read/send whatsapp messages(web.whatsapp.com). Or any other program, whether it is social media or other service related program that can use computer to read/send messages. How user can be notified if one of the browsers got message? I checked Notification API from mozilla and chrome notifications but it seems you have to have your own app to run it. But I need something that allows me to be notified on top of someones app, maybe some browser extension I can install? Notification can be in form of popup messages in the browser, google notifications(for example, when you get new email, google can notify you), or even system tray icon/message if none exists.